# Proper way to Update model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

On my Django project, I have a form on my `my_account_edit.html` page and the values of this form where they are displayed are on my `my_account.html` which I created.

I need this form to update the model instance if it exists or create a new one for the logged in user.

What's the best way to execute this?

Comment: You should read [ask] and check how to post a [mcve]. Also your questions doesn't show any effort you've done to solve this yourself. Do the basic [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) to learn how to submit forms and update/create models.

Comment: @dirkgroten I've been debugging this for the past couple days but I keep on creating model instances and not updating. If you look at my last post you can see my code there my friend.

Comment: Your other question already has an answer. If you don't pass `instance=...` to your ModelForm you're creating a new object. You need to pass the `instance` that you're updating to your form when initialising the form. `HomeForm(data=request.POST, instance=<instance-to-update>)`

Comment: @dirkgroten I was debugging this yesterday and got a little lost.. Once I do that would I need to make the page where the values that are being displayed a `DetailView` as well?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Not sure why for you displaying the values is related to how to update the instance.

Comment: @dirkgroten On my Django project when a user makes a form submission on `my_account_edit.html` the values are then displayed of the currently logged in user on `my_account.hmtl`. I'm trying to figure out the best way possible to achieve this.

Comment: Those are different views. So they are totally unrelated. When the form submission is successful, you normally redirect to the other view. It's also unrelated to this question.

Comment: @dirkgroten ok. I'll start debugging again and add your suggestion. thank you my friend.